# How to detect if a form is loading in wpf

Tags: vb.net, events, constructor

I have a program in which I create a new form which contains several combo box. When I create the form, I want to fill one of those combo box with a value depending of the time of the day. This so far is working fine.

When I fill the value of in the combo box, the SelectionChanged event is triggered, which is normal. However, I would like to prevent the combo box to do something different if I am still within the form constructor. In this case, I want to show a message box when the selection is changed by a user only.

Something like

```
If Form.IsFinishedLoading then
    'Do something
Else
    'Do something else
End if
```

What I usually do in those case is set up a boolean which tells me if I am still in my loading sequence, which is working, but I wonder if there are any other and better way to do this.

Regards

Comment: What about using dispatcher?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Dispatcher to fire your code at a later DispatcherPriority than Loaded, such as Input.

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, New Action(Sub() dowhat?))
```

Heres a little example thats implemented...

http://sambourton.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/execute-a-method-asynchronously-using-the-dispatcher-queue/

Another great link describing DispatcherPriority enums in ascending order of priority, lowest to highest...

http://sambourton.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/tips-and-tricks-with-the-dispatcher-and-dispatcherpriority-in-wpf/